# OracleCallableStatement V/S CallableStatement

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

i just wanted to know the difference between OracleCallableStatement and CallableStatement in terms of performance and effectiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OracleCallableStatement` is an Oracle-specific interface which ultimately extends the standard `java.sql.CallableStatement` interface.

Unless you need access to the Oracle-specific functionality in that interface, you should not refer to it in your code, but should write your code against the `CallableStatement` interface only. This is general good practice for all JDBC code, and keeps your application portable between drivers and databases.

There is no performance or effectiveness difference - you're actually using the same thing.

Comment: Surely this only applies if you care about portability.  And what if you want to use Oracle specific extensions?

Comment: @cagcowboy: You should *always* care about portability.  What if Oracle rewrites its driver and changes that interface?

Comment: Nope, OCS is an interface too. If you need using anonymous PL/SQL blocks ... you can use OCS, otherwise just use CS

Answer (score 1):

The [OracleCallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html) extends CallableStatement, so an OracleCallableStatement is a CallableStatement too. The performance won't differ at all, but if you don't need Oracle's special (and non standard) features, keep using CallableStatement, that will help you change your database easier. By the way you will find more developers who are familiar with CallableStatement than the latter.

Comment: Another note is using connection pools, some JDBC pools, have a feature to pool prepared statements (and a callable statement is a prepared statement too). I believe you can't cast the CallableStatement which you get from the pool to OracleCallableStatement (except for pools which are implemented by proxying the main objects).